# c++ Lock class skeleton

Tags: c++, stl

From Effective STL (by Scott Meyers) Item 12, below is the skeleton of a c++ Lock class.

```
template<typename Container>
class Lock {
public:
    Lock(const Container& container)
    : c(container)
    {
        getMutexFor(c);
    }

    ~Lock()
    {
        releaseMutexFor(c);
    }
private:
    const Container& c;
};
```

The point I do not understand is why the mutex is acquired on the lock's c private member (itself copy-constructed from the container we want to take a lock on).

Will the following effectively lock v (and why)?

```
vector<int> v;
{
    Lock<vector<int> > lock(v);
    ...
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The point I do not understand is why the mutex is acquired on the lock's c private member (itself copy-constructed from the container we want to take a lock on).

`c` is a *reference* to the container passed to the lock's constructor, not a copy. So that very same container is getting locked.

> Will the following effectively lock v (and why)?

```
vector<int> v;
{
    Lock<vector<int> > lock(v);
    ...
}
```

Yes, `v` will be locked in the scope defined by the `{}` (assuming the locking mechanism has been correctly implemented, of course.)

Note that this lock is only useful if all other code accessing `v` locks the same mutex, for example, by following the same convention of using the lock guard.

See also [`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard).

Comment: lock_guard protects a code section, not the vector itself ... I am not sure  about the meaning of the question. The vector is unprotected, what is protected is the code between brackets.

Comment: @MelVisoMartinez It is an example from a book and it is pretty obvious what it is trying to show.

Comment: You are right, but I'm not sure if he understand the same by asking if v gets locked...

Comment: @MelVisoMartinez Yes, that's quite vague. I added a clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point is that `c` is not copy-constructed, it is a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization).

Answer (score 0):

Effectively is a reference, so is the same object passed to the constructor as @juanchopanza says. Relative to the second question, "Will the following effectively lock v (and why)?" I think not. This is an example and Container must be a special class that holds a mutex. We need to see the rest of the code. But vector dont have, as long as I know, internal mutex locks.

Comment: The code doesn't require the container to have a mutex. It is perfectly possible for `getMutexFor` and `releaseMutexFor` to have the means to map vector instances to mutexes. But I guess that isn't shown because it isn't the point of the example.